# iOS push/local notifications with image like in iMessage

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to display an image (custom view) in Notification Center when app receives push/local notification. e.g -

[image]

or

[image]
How could I achieve the same? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The notification payload contains up to 256 bytes long. You can't send an image with it however you can send image URL with payload and show it in your application.

The official documentation does not provide information about this. Currently, it is possible but I guess this feature is Apple exclusive.

Adding to that what you have shown in the images is called Widget, you can create it using this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83809/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial).

Comment: In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes.

Can we show this widget inside notification tab of Notification Center?

Comment: Did you see that second image I've shared with this question?

Comment: @AmolPrakash please check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html), as the Widget are used to show app extensions in the Today view. That means it showed if it is scheduled for today. In 2nd image a ticket is booked for today, so the calendar will automatically notify using the Widget.